# Add \numberline in TOC for part with scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, titletoc

I'm using the `scrbook` document class for a publication. In order to properly format the part entries in the table of contents, I would like to write an entry like

```
\contentsline {part}{\numberline{I}Introduction}{9}{part.1}
```

instead of

```
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}Introduction}{9}{part.1}
```

I have no idea how to achieve this, but I mentioned, that this is true for all other levels (chapter, section, subsection and so on) already.

**Edit:**

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\setkomafont{part}{\Huge}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\huge}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\thispagestyle{empty}\centering\sffamily\bfseries\huge}{}{0mm}{{\fontsize{36pt}{0pt}\selectfont Part \thepart\\\vspace{3mm}}}[]

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}[3pc]{\addvspace{3pc}\filcenter}{\sffamily\bfseries PART \thecontentslabel\\*[.2pc]\large}{\sffamily\bfseries\large}{}[\addvspace{.5pc}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Testpart}
\section{Just a sample section}

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:**

The problem seems to be the `\titleformat` line. I am not able to find any hint in the documentation of titlesec for this behaviour.

```
\documentclass[10pt,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% comment the following line out and check *.toc-file
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\huge}{}{0mm}{{Part \thepart\\\vspace{3mm}}}[]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Testpart}
\section{Just a sample section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example with the settings of the toc. Very often most of the settings can be done with KOMA itself.

Comment: I get `\contentsline {part}{\numberline {I}Part}{1}{part.1}`; but you're mentioning `titletoc` in the tags, so that could be the cause. Please, provide a minimal example.

Comment: Please excuse the inconvenience regarding the minimal working example, I've prepared it, but simply forgotten to paste it. I noticed, that the first version is written to TOC, when the line `\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\thispagestyle{empty}\centering\sffamily\bfseries\huge}{}{0mm}{{\fontsize{36pt}{0pt}\selectfont Part \thepart\\\vspace{3mm}}}[]` is present. Otherwise, the TOC entry is correctly made with `\numberline`.

Comment: @saint: So what you're saying is there is a conflict between [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) and [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) in the sense that your ToC entry  doesn't match what you specify (via `titletoc`) when you also specify a title format (via `titlesec`)?

Comment: @Werner: No, it seems that there is no conflict between titletoc and titlesec. The problem seems to be the line with `\titleformat`. I've attached a new minimal working example, showing the problem. I found nothing in the documention of titlesec regarding this behaviour.

Comment: You write "In order to properly format [...] I would like to write [...]", but I'm still not sure what the "proper format" is. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @lockstep: In the end I would like to format all entries of part level in my TOC. The problem is that no `\numberline` appears in the *.toc file for part entries. Instead the part number will be printed with a `\hspace{1em}` following.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) (p 8, section **3.7. Other Package Options**), you need to specify the package option `newparttoc`:

> `newparttoc` `oldparttoc` (Package options)
>
> Standard parts write the toc entry number in a non standard way. You
>   may change that with `newparttoc` so that titletoc or a similar
>   package can manipulate the entry. (That works only if `\part` has been
>   redeﬁned.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,listof=totoc,numbers=noenddot,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
% comment the following line out and check *.toc-file
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\huge}{}{0mm}{{Part \thepart\\\vspace{3mm}}}[]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Testpart}
\section{Just a sample section}
\end{document}
```

This leaves you with the `.toc` entries resembling:

```
\contentsline {part}{\numberline {I}First Testpart}{3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}Just a sample section}{5}
```

Comment: Thank you really, really much. I've spent over two hours until now in solving the problem. Although I read the `titlesec` documentation, the meaning of the package option `newparttoc` was not obvious to me.