# Add dot to part number in ToC using tocstyle

Tags: table-of-contents

I had a previous question on how to add dots in ToC using `tocstyle` package: [Add a dot after chapter and section/figure/table number in ToC/LoF/LoT using tocstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274237/add-a-dot-after-chapter-and-section-figure-table-number-in-toc-lof-lot-using-toc). However the dot is not applied to `part`s. How can I do that using `tocstyle`? Or in general, how can I format part number in ToC using `tocstyle`?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer here [Add \numberline in TOC for part with scrbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37837/add-numberline-in-toc-for-part-with-scrbook). So all the credits are for Werner for proving the answer.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec} % see pages 8 and 10 from the manual
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\centering\huge}{}{0mm}{{Part \thepart\\\vspace{3mm}}}[] % \part needs to be redefined

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{This is a part}
\chapter{This is a chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]